# Issue with Hard Reset the iPAD (9.3.2) that is in Single App mode

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-device-management, guided-access

I have an iPad application that runs in Single App Mode. Now if I Hard Reset(Home + Lock button) the iPad there are two different behaviours that I came accross while testing the Single App Mode in different iPads:

```
In some iPads after hard reset, the same application starts on the device and the device remains in Single App Mode.

In some iPads after hard reset, the same application does not starts and the iPad is no longer in Single App mode.
```

So which one is the correct behaviour and how can I achieve same behaviour on each device.

Please let me know if any further clarifications are needed regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad should launch the app and stay in single-app mode when it restarts after a hard reset. That's the behavior that I get on my devices, although I can't state with certainty that the second scenario (app does not start) never happens.